# Learning Curve Plot (Logistic Regression) on CDSW - Matplotlib plotting several plots instead of just one

Tags: python, matplotlib, machine-learning, plot, cloudera

Up until yesterday I had no problem plotting a particular plot but since earlier today I'm getting several plots instead of just the one.

The code below is meant to generate just one plot but somehow im getting a lot
of different ones.

How can I fix this?

Update: I was able to get the plot on Jupyter online just fine, I think the problem might be something related to Cloudera Data Science Workbench, any ideas?

data: http://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/machine-learning-databases/breast-cancer-wisconsin/wdbc.data

The code I´m using to plot

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
%matplotlib inline
from sklearn import preprocessing
from sklearn.model_selection import learning_curve
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler
from sklearn.decomposition import PCA
from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegression
from sklearn.pipeline import make_pipeline

df = pd.read_csv('http://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/'
                 'machine-learning-databases/'
                 'breast-cancer-wisconsin/wdbc.data'
                 , header=None)

X = df.loc[:,2:].values
y = df.loc[:,1].values

le = preprocessing.LabelEncoder()

y = le.fit_transform(y)


X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test =\
train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.20, \
                 stratify=y, random_state=1)



pipe_lr = make_pipeline(StandardScaler(), 
                        LogisticRegression(penalty='l2', 
                                           random_state=1))

train_sizes, train_scores, test_scores = \
learning_curve(estimator = pipe_lr, X = X_train,
               y = y_train,
               train_sizes=np.linspace(0.1, 1.0, 10),
               cv = 10, n_jobs = 1)

train_mean = np.mean(train_scores, axis = 1)
train_std = np.std(train_scores, axis = 1)
test_mean = np.mean(test_scores, axis = 1)
test_std = np.std(test_scores, axis = 1)

plt.plot(train_sizes, train_mean, color = 'blue',
         marker = 'o', markersize = 5, 
         label = 'training_accuracy')

plt.fill_between(train_sizes,
                 train_mean + train_std,
                 train_mean - train_std,
                 alpha = 0.5, color = 'blue')

plt.plot(train_sizes, test_mean, color = 'green',
         linestyle = '--', marker = 's', markersize = 5,
         label = 'validation accuracy')

plt.fill_between(train_sizes,
                 test_mean + test_std,
                 test_mean - test_std,
                 alpha = 0.15, color = 'green')
plt.grid()
plt.xlabel("Number of training samples")
plt.ylabel('Accuracy')
plt.legend(loc='lower right')
plt.ylim([0.85, 1.025])
plt.show()
```

[image]
[image]

Using Jupyter Online I am able to get the plot I want

Do I need to reset something on matplotlib in CDSW?

[image]

Comment: This is too much code and too many images for such a simple issue. Please have a look at [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and improve your question.

Comment: I removed most of the images, my idea was that people could see what´s happening to my plot. As for the code, Its the minimal to generate the plot above.

Answer (score 2):

Cloudera Data Science Workbench processes each line of code individually (unlike notebooks that process code per-cell). This means if your plot requires multiple commands, you will see incomplete plots in the workbench as each line is processed.

To get around this behavior, wrap all your plotting commands in one Python function. Cloudera Data Science Workbench will then process the function as a whole, and not as individual lines. You should then see your plots as expected.

The above information is from https://www.cloudera.com/documentation/data-science-workbench/latest/topics/cdsw_visualize_report.html

Answer (score 1):

You probably need to be more explicit about the figure and axes you're plotting on.

```
fig = pyplot.figure()
ax = fig.add_axes(1,1,1)
ax.plot(...)
ax.fill_between(...)
```

et cetera

Comment: The problem is, this exact same code was working up until yesterday. I was thinking that maybe I needed to reset something in matplotlib